# Add product to cart from third party and view products added in cart

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

Can I add products to my cart using `Magento API` and when I view cart, I should find that products listed in cart. I am using **Magento 2.2**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add product to cart using magento 2 rest api , **Below is the steps:**

**First of all empty cart should be created using request with empty body:**

```
[POST] {base URL}/rest/V1/carts/mine
```

**In response you will get ID of your cart/quote.**

**Now you can add items to your cart using below details:**

```
[POST] {base URL}/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
{
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": <cart ID received from previous call>,
    "sku": "product_sku",
    "qty": 10
  }
}
```

**In response you should get your cart item data:**

```
{
  "item_id": 1,
  "sku": "product_sku",
  "qty": 10,
  "name": "Simple Product",
  "price": 123,
  "product_type": "simple",
  "quote_id": "1"
}
```

Comment: This will add product in my quote but when I redirect to magento store i don't find that products added in my cart as a guest user.

Comment: Well something is missing at your end , i have tried same api with the same details and when i go back to store i am able to see product added with cart as an guest user !!!

Comment: Following is the response I am getting in response of API to create empty cart:

`{
    "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "self"
    }
}`

Comment: Its because of token is invalid with its permissions

Comment: Tokens are required when creating cart for registered user. I want to perform same as a guest user.

Comment: Hey anybody got solution for this? Igot same problem quotetable got entry but due to session id it is not reflecting on frontend